# Alternative for Indices(in Swift) in C#

Tags: c#

Have we a simple like in Swift to make subscripting the collection, in ascending order?

In Swift it's really going to be easy by calling *Indices*.

I know I can do like this:

```
for (int i = myArray.Count -1; i>=0; i--)

Console.WriteLine(i);  //consistently going to zero
```

But anyway, it's tedious.

Comment: [`Array.Reverse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.reverse?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: Also, I think your `for` example has some problems. First you print out `i`, not `myArray[i]`, it would give an "out of bounds" exception on the first, and would never print out (or use) the 0th element. You probably want `for (int i = myArray.Count -1; i>=0; i--) { ... }`.

Comment: @RonBeyer It not actually what i need, but thanks, now this code will completely change Indices in Swift. And also thanks for example's correct :)

Comment: Hey @JustKamil is your question answered? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @Saamer Yes, I just though maybe C# also have yet assembled method like Indices

Answer (score 0):

You can use OrderBy methods to sort your arrays/lists.

```
var array = new int[] { 10, 13, 2, 7, 1, 8, 15 };
var ascSorted = array.OrderBy(x => x);
var descSorted = array.OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

This works for objects as well as primitives.

```
// Let's say you have a collection of Person objects like this:
class Person {
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}

var peopleByFirstName = collectionOfPeople.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName);
var peopleByLastThenFirst = collectionOfPeople
    .OrderBy(x => x.LastName)
        .ThenBy(x => x.FirstName)
```